# Symfony 2.8 - problem with Session and Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, warnings, fatal-error

I deployed small app in symfony 2.8 on host without ssh. Copied all files without cache and log, cloned DB.
When i go to address: address.com/web/app.php, app show errors:

```
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/tmp/sess_9ff0c94b9bd261554814764d051524e0, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 431

Warning: include(/web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/vendor/composer/../twig/twig/lib/Twig/Cache/Filesystem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/vendor/composer/../twig/twig/lib/Twig/Cache/Filesystem.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/httpd-clients/php-7.2.10/lib/php') in /vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: include(/web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/vendor/composer/../twig/twig/lib/Twig/Cache/Filesystem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/vendor/composer/../twig/twig/lib/Twig/Cache/Filesystem.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/httpd-clients/php-7.2.10/lib/php') in /vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Twig_Cache_Filesystem" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement? in /web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3212 
Stack trace: #0 /web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/app/cache/prod/classes.php(3149): Twig_Environment->setCache('/web/clients/ww...') 
#1 /web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(2476): Twig_Environment->__construct(Object(Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader), Array) 
#2 /web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2271): appProdProjectContainer->getTwigService() 
#3 /web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(2505): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('twig') 
#4 /web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2271): appProdProjectContainer->getTwig_Controller_ExceptionService() 
#5 /web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/app/cache in /app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 3212

Warning: SessionHandler::write(): open(/web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/tmp/sess_9ff0c94b9bd261554814764d051524e0, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 435

Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: /web/clients/www/3/a/8/8/address.com/tmp) in %s%02d on line 0
```

I add chmod 777 to cache and log dir. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Clear your cache and try again

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical permissions issue. You should clear you cache, then add recursively the appropriate permissions like this:

```
chmod -R 775 /cache
```

Comment: `0775` should suffice

Comment: I agree, just copied the permissions from the OP because it wasn't the main subject of the question. In any case, one should properly set the permissions to all the files of his project.

Comment: `OP` already stated he did `chmod` the cache and log directories though

Comment: yes, i believe the problem is that he didn't do that recursively but only in the parent directory

Comment: Have you set up another symfony project on this server?

Comment: I created new project and deploy. Work. So i try to make new project and copy all from old project